# Can somebody tell me how I am supposed to be using blogs.dir for network / MU sites?

Tags: content, multisite, configuration

I think `blogs.dir` is supposed to be used to separate content for the different blogs on a network install of Wordpress (MU or 3.0+ with networks enabled), however, I've not been able to find a clear guide to using it. Can someone shed some light and maybe post a few links to information on how to set it up, what to put in there, what the permissions should be set to, etc. ?

Comment: don't worry about it, WP handles this

Comment: @One-Trick-Pony is right, WP handles all of this, apart of course from making the directory in your wp-content folder, that is the one thing you'll have to do yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blogs.dir` was the way to handle specific blog plugins and themes when it was WordPress-MU
but since version 3 came out and the WordPress-MU was integrated into WordPress Core and introduced WordPress Multisite, that's no longer the story.

WordPress Handles the creation of the new blogs/sites in the database and mainly in the background so you won't see too many things changing, but it also includes a new menu in the admin "Super Admin"

[image]

which lets you handle the content for all sites in one place and they all site in one place.

so basically WordPress handle this issue of `blogs.dir' for you.